# getting russell 3000 membership historically

Tags: market-data

Hi All: Does any know of there is any code  somewhere for obtaining the russell 3000 constituents for 2017, 2018 and 2019. If not, then is there a company that sells it ? I imagine russell does but I haven't contacted them yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Bloomberg, `RAY Index MEMB <GO>` lists the constituents back as far as 1995-01-31.

Comment: thanks. I don't have access to bloomberg but, if anyone can bothered doing that t for me, my email is  my name 2@gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Norgate Data provides paid subscription access to historical index constituents and delisted data, including data on the Russell 3000, with Russell 3000 back to 1990.

Disclosure:  I am a co-owner of Norgate Data.

Comment: thanks for info but a friend was kind enough to provide it to me.